# Record is not getting locked in via Approval Process

Tags: lightning, approval-process, locking

We have enabled a approval process with initial action as "Lock the Record", once the record is submitted on criteria met in the field history we could see the record is locked. But in the lightning view the record is still coming as editable for non admins without having modify all permission.

When i access same record as non admin in classic, i could see the record is locked but with a button to unlock it. Any reason the record is not locked in the lightning view?

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: can you try to edit it and click save? I think you can't save it, if its locked

Comment: @prem22 unfortunately it is editing as well

Answer (score 0):

Record is not getting locked in via Approval Process

User perms might behave differently in Classic and lightning, as far as approval records are concerned.

Check this feed out:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8DYISA3